# `jdn. heiraten` gegen `jdn. trauen`

Tags: etymology, meaning, verb, noun, synonym

Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen `jdn. heiraten` und `jdn. trauen`? Ist das "Ergebnis" eine Ehe oder eine Heirat und nennt sich der "Prozess" eine Hochzeit oder eine Trauung? Was bedeutet `die Vermählung`? Benutzt man einige der Wörter eher in einer bestimmten Situation und wenn ja, in welchen?

P.S. Ich habe schon die Frage [“jdn. heiraten” vs. “sich mit jdm. verheiraten”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/637/jdn-heiraten-vs-sich-mit-jdm-verheiraten) gelesen, fand aber dort keine passende Antworten.

Comment: War nur Schreibfehler und danach einfach kopiert. Es macht wenig Sinn hier über andere Bedeutungen von `trauen` gemeinsam mit `heiraten` zu fragen. Danke für die Anmerkung!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Heiraten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heiraten) bedeutet eine Ehe eingehen. Man ist also entweder Braut oder Bräutigam.
[Sich vermählen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vermaehlen) ist ein Synonym zu heiraten, in meinem Verständnis formaler und definitiv seltener verwendet.

[Trauen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trauen) bedeutet nicht, dass man selbst den Bund der Ehe eingeht, sondern jemanden ehelich verbindet.

> Der Pastor traut das Ehepaar.

Entsprechend ist das Äquivalent zu heiraten: [sich trauen lassen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trauen_lassen)

*Heiraten*, *sich trauen lassen* und *sich vermählen* ist der *Vorgang* der Eheschließung, während *Hochzeit*, *Trauung* und *Vermählung* das Event an sich bezeichnen.

Anmerkung:
*Vermählen* kann auch synonym zu *trauen* verwendet werden, dieser Gebrauch ist aber veraltet:

> Er vermählte seine Tochter mit einem reichen Erben.

Ergänzung:
Mir ist aufgefallen, dass ich das Wort *Heirat* ignoriert habe. [Heirat](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heirat) bedeutet laut Duden sowohl *das Eingehen einer Ehe* als auch in einer *ehelichen Verbindung* sein. Ich glaube aber, dass es üblicher als Synonym zu *Hochzeit* verwendet wird. Möchte man auf den Ehebund Bezug nehmen, ist es üblicher von *verheiratet sein* zu reden:

> Ist er verheiratet oder geschieden?

Comment: Man kann auch *jemanden verheiraten*, also als transitives Verb. Ist evtl. Umgangssprache, geht in die Richtung *ein Paar trauen*, also die Rolle des Geistlichen. Kann auch benutzt werden von einer dritten Partei, die eine Hochzeit entscheidend angebahnt/organisiert hat, z.B. bei arrangierten Ehen.

Answer (score 3):

Zum Unterschied zwischen Hochzeit und Trauung: 
Die Trauung ist nur die formale Prozedur auf dem Standesamt und in der Kirche, während die Hochzeit die Trauung und das meist anschließende Fest umfaßt.
Im übrigen stimme ich Em1 zu, außer daß ich das Wort Heirat noch nie tatsächlich im Gebrauch gehört oder gelesen habe.

Comment: So unüblich ist es aber nicht mal, wie [eine Suche in der Zeit zeigt](http://www.zeit.de/suche/index?q=heirat), auch wenn es oft in Kombination mit einem anderen Wort verwendet wird (*Heiratsversprechen*, *Heiratsantrag*, ...). Dass es aber bedeutend seltener verwendet wird, that's true.